# Send a product's custom feature in order confirmation email

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, prestashop

I want to send the "units per box" custom feature in my confirmation mails in prestashop.

Here's an example if what I want to do

```
$myprod = new Product($product['id_product']);
$features = $myprod->getFrontFeatures(1));

foreach(from=$features item=feature)
{
  if ($feature.name == "Units per box")
  {
     $UnitsPerBox = $feature.value|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8';
  }
}
```

However I need to do this within a php file (`PaymentModule.php`) rather than a tpl file, so that code won't work. 
If anybody could point me in the right direction of how to achieve this with php it'd be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I used the example code provided which seems to get inside the array but doesn't return any values

When I run some test code like this

```
$myprod = new Product($product['id_product']);
$features = $myprod->getFrontFeatures(1);
$UnitsPerBox .= '100';
foreach ($features as $feature) 
{
  $UnitsPerBox .= '200';
  if ($feature->name == 'Units Per Box') 
  {
    $UnitsPerBox .= htmlentities($feature->value, 'ENT_QUOTES', 'UTF-8');   
    $UnitsPerBox .= $feature->name;
  }
  else
  {
    $UnitsPerBox .= $feature->name;
    $UnitsPerBox .= htmlentities($feature->name, 'ENT_QUOTES', 'UTF-8');
    $UnitsPerBox .= htmlentities($feature->value, 'ENT_QUOTES', 'UTF-8');
  }
}
```

I get this output: "100200200200200200"

Any help would be great, thanks.

Thanks, 
Andrew

**EDIT: Solution**

Got it working in the end, thanks for the help

```
$myprod = new Product($product['id_product']);
$features = $myprod->getFrontFeatures(1);
foreach ($features as $feature) 
{
foreach ($feature as $key => $value) 
{
    if($value == "Units per box")
    {
        $UnitsPerBox = $feature['value'];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Before your `foreach` loop, `var_dump($features)` to see what objects the array actually contains. Seems like it doesn't have what you expect it to have in it. Also, `$UnitsPerBox` starts as "100" and you use the `.=` operator inside the loop to keep appending "200". You probably just want `=`.

Comment: Thanks. There were more arrays inside the arrays, it was those arrays that I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myprod = new Product($product['id_product']);
$features = $myprod->getFrontFeatures(1);

foreach ($features as $feature) {
   if ($feature->name == 'Units per box') {
      $UnitsPerBox = htmlentities($feature->value, 'ENT_QUOTES', 'UTF-8');
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a million, this seems to get inside the features array but doesn't get any values. I've edited my question to show what's happening, if you have any ideas it'd be great to hear them, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Smarty template code.  In that case, the function you're looking for is `htmlentities()`:

```
foreach($features as $feature)
{
  if ($feature->name == "Units per box")
  {
     $UnitsPerBox = htmlentities($feature->value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my file

```
classes/PaymentModule.php
```

I can print short and Long Description of the product, but I'm just not being able to put the features of the product on the order confirmation mail template, I came up with a solution using this page and also this https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/658353-15-add-products-features-in-order-confirmation-email/, using this last solution I was just able to print the ID of the order confirmation.

I added the following around line 353

```
$lesfeatures = Product::getFrontFeaturesStatic((int)$id_lang,      `$product['id_product']);`

foreach ($lesfeatures as $key => $lafeature) {                        
    $machin .= print_r($lafeature);
    $machin .= $lafeature['id_feature'].'name:'.$lafeature['name'].'value:'.$lafeature['value'].'<br>';}
```

and then the following around line 400

`<strong>'.$product['name'].(isset($product['attributes']) ? ' - '.$product['attributes'] : '').'</strong>'.$machin.`'

That's when I just get the Order ID

This is my current working code around line 400 for printing descriptions

```
<strong>
Cantidad de Piezas: '.$product['quantity'].'
<br/>
'.$product['name'].(isset($product['attributes']) ? ' - '.$product['attributes'] : '').'
<br/>Descripci贸n: '.$product['description_short'].'
</strong>
```